# precision recall for depth estimation

Tags: image-processing, precision, depth, estimation, precision-recall

I used [Make3D dataset](http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/data.html)  to estimate depth maps. I want to calculate precision and recall for each test image. But i have no idea how to do it with images specially how to find True/false positive  and false negative from my results and the data.
I know only that :

```
Precision = tp/(tp+fp)
Recall = tp/(tp+fn)
With tp=True Positives, fp=False Positives and fn=False Negatives.
```

So how to calculate tp,fp and fn when i have pixels ?

Comment: You have check for literature on this topic and find out what are the performance parameters that is used for depth maps. That will help you to find the right metric.

Comment: Sir, Which topic ?

Comment: Estimating depth maps